# I just finish the donut course of blender guru where do I go next?

Tags: modeling

I just finish the 2.8 donut course of blender guru and now I am confuse where do I start practicing

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to improve on your skills is to join a community, and blender has a large community.
You could join these communities to see other people's workflow, styles and ways of working with blender.
My two favourite communities are:

**Blenderartists:** in this community you get to see fellow blender artist workflows, reels and the community creates challenges weekly to help you grow and learn faster. Here is the link
[www.blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org)

**BlenderNation:** is a very great community here you could get links to any tutorial in blender, assets (paid or free), documentation and so on, basically it an informative and educative community. Here is the link

[www.blendernation.com](https://www.blendernation.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Model whatever comes to your head as long as your next object is more complex than the previous one and needs tools/options you didn't use before. Just explore Blender and forget "have-to-do lists". The communities such as Blender Nation are helpful as well as they i.a. have info about add-ons, repos, render farms etc.